# CakePHP adding async to script tag

Tags: php, cakephp, asynchronous, cakephp-1.3

In Google's PageSpeed reports that there are some Blocking Javascript required to be async. From [this article](http://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/) I knew that I have to place async attribute to my scripts tag:

```
<script async src="http://third-party.com/resource.js"></script>
```

In cakePHP, I don't able to achieve this exactly, I just able to get:

```
<script async="async" src="http://third-party.com/resource.js"></script>
```

Using the Html's script method as follows:

```
$html->script(array('jsfile1', 'jsfile2'), array('async' => 'async'));
```

I tried `array('async')` but it prints out 0='0' in the script tag

How could I make it print just `async` in the script tag. Also, how could I make it available in the link tag of css too?

**Notice: I use CakePHP 1.3x**

Comment: I am looking for this in cakephp 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Checking the source code](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/source-class-Helper.html#___formatAttribute) indicates that there is no way to implement such tag as it's obvious that the format of attributes is `%s="%s"`.

If you really need this I think the easiest way now is to provide your own customized `HtmlHelper` by extending the core `HtmlHelper`, and overwrite the `_formatAttribute` function:

**Note: this is for CakePHP 1.3.x only and it's pretty messy as it can't specify `className` in the helpers array. CakePHP 2.x provides a cleaner way to overwrite default core helper with ease, but it's not what OP wanted so I'll not put it up here**

1. Create `app/views/helpers/custom_html.php`:

   ```
   <?php
   App::import('Helper', 'Html');
   class CustomHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper {
       function __formatAttribute($key, $value, $escape = true) {
           if (in_array($key, array('async', 'defer'))) {
               return $key;
           }
           return parent::__formatAttribute($key, $value, $escape);
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your `app_controller.php` or whatever main controller that need this, use the `CustomHtmlHelper` by:

   ```
   var $helpers = array('CustomHtml');
   ```
3. And in your view, you can now start using `async` or `defer` tag. Feel free to extend this array if you see fit.

   ```
   echo $this->CustomHtml->script('test', array('async' => 'async'));
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is opened new scopes for me.

Comment: @Lionel Chan. Thanks for your answer. How to add async and defer parameters to script in cakephp 2.x? You said cakephp 2.x has a cleaner way. Can you explain?

Comment: @Gunaseelan unfortunately there is no easy way to do it too. You will need to do the similar overwrites to the HtmlHelper. What I meant back then is that you can specify "className" in the controller's `$helpers` array, so that you still can use `$this->Html->script` in your view, with the "enhancements" that you put into the custom class. Check the configuration here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-and-configuring-helpers (search `className`)

Comment: @LionelChan Thanks I will look into the link